# How to add barbutton programmatically with image

Tags: iphone, uiimage, uibarbuttonitem

I am creating a barbutton programmatically. But it can't fix into screen.  Help me in solve this problem.

Screenshot:

[image]

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"request.png"];
UIBarButtonItem *button2;

//[button2 setWidth:55];
button2= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image style:UIBarStyleDefault target:self action:@selector(requestButton)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button2;

[button2 release];
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fix into screen"?

Comment: on the top of the screen have seen the register button.there i am getting gap which is in the screen shot.please guide me to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"request.png"];    
UIButton* requestButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[requestButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[requestButton addTarget:self action:@selector(requestButton) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *button2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:requestButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button2;
```

Answer (score 4):

I do this normally this way:

```
self.myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_pressed.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 121, 36);

[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem * aBarButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myButton] autorelease];

[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:aBarButton, nil]];
```

Comment: i cant get u can u please tell me what is tool bar.

Comment: Ah sorry, a UIToolbar is almost the same as the navigationbar. You can skip the last line and just use the aBarButton and assign it to your navbar.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"request-1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 36);

[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(requestButton) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem * aBarButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myButton] autorelease];


self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = aBarButton;



[myButton release];
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually create the UIImageView, then a UITapGestureRecognizer and i add it to the UIImageView, and finally i create the UIBarbuttonItem:

```
    //UIImageView where the image is shown
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"]];
    imageViewSettings.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25);
    imageViewSettings.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    //TapGesture
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(methodToTrigger)];

    //Adding the gesture to the ImageView
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

    //Creating the barButtonItem
    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:imageView];

    //Finally add the button to the navigationBar
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;
```