# Navigation bar item adjustment in IOS

Tags: ios

i have a nav bar button. I have use image for it , but i'm facing an issue that if i click on the button it changes it position and moves down from nav bar into the view  of my view controller. My code is,

```
 UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                initWithTitle:@""
                                style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                target:self
                                action:@selector(rightBtnClicked:)];
[rightButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"right.png"]];
rightButton.tintColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/5419719/4955401 ?

Comment: The link u provide does not show button in nav bar. @ParvBhasker

Comment: what happend in `rightBtnClicked`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked this is working

```
    UIButton *someButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
[someButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_1148.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[someButton addTarget:self action:@selector(requestButton)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


UIBarButtonItem *barButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:someButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=barButton;
```

or you can do like this

```
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(requestButton)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *mailbutton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=mailbutton;
```

Comment: @umer -  did you get time to check this as i just checked it worked in xcode 8.3.3.

Comment: I want this in white color. @Parv Bhasker

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@“right.png”] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(rightButtonClicked:)];
   self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;
```

Comment: Its not showing me the image as i followed ur code. @Brijesh Shiroya

Answer (score 0):

try like this, i hope it will help you.

**// OBJC**

```
UIImage *img_table =[UIImage imageNamed:@"right.png"];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, img_table.size.width, img_table.size.height);
[button setImage:img_table forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:img_table forState: UIControlStateSelected];
[button addTarget: self action:@selector(rightBtnClicked:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
barButton.tintColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;
```

**// Swift**

```
let img_table = UIImage(named: "right.png")
    let button = UIButton.init(type: UIButtonType.custom)
    button.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: (img_table?.size.width)!, height: (img_table?.size.height)!)
    button.setImage(img_table, for: UIControlState.normal)
    button.setImage(img_table, for: UIControlState.selected)

    button.addTarget(self, action: @selector(rightBtnClicked:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: button)
    barButton.tintColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
```

Answer (score 0):

**The issue is that you need to provide a frame to the image.** So Take a UIButton and set image and action to it. And then add UIButton to UIBarButtonItem.

Below is working code for you:

```
UIButton *button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"right.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(rightButtonClicked:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 53, 31)];
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to for the information :) . @Nirmalsinh